# How to get actual width of div when max-width is set?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with some text which has a `max-width` value and it needs a `display:block`.  How can i get the actual `width` using jQuery?

```
<style type="text/css">div{display:block; max-width:600px}</style>
<div>hello world</div>
```

Currently this returns `600` when the value should be much lower.

```
var ww = $('div').width(); // innerWidth() returns same value
```

Comment: Your div will have the same width as its container given your code, to a max of 600. So if your container is greater than 600px then it will return 600 since it is maxed out

Comment: thank you, any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: You can float it but I don't know if that will affect your layout or not or set display to inline-block or you can wrap your text in a span and get the width of the span. Lots of ways to do it

Comment: What width do you expect instead? Why would it be much lower?

Comment: @showdev i was hoping for the width created from the text

Comment: @showdev OP is thinking the div is an inline element

Comment: [Why do you need to know the width? This probably a bad question because it's an XY Problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this code.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};

$("div").textWidth()
```

This function passed the content of the div to a temporal span because this element is an inline element. It has no width or height, so the text inside them have the real width.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. Code dumps are not as useful for future readers.

Comment: In case poster does not add explanation - he is wrapping the content of the div with a span, grab the width of the span then replace the div content back to the original content. Returning the width the OP is looking for

Comment: Span is an inline element. It has no width or height, so the text inside them have the width real.

Comment: @SebastianLorenzo you should edit your answer and add the explanation

Answer (score 3):

The `div` element expands to the height of its container by default, but you could try setting the display attribute to `inline-block`.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#showWidthBtn").click(function() {
    alert($("div").width());
  });
  
});
```

```css
div { background: #eee; max-width: 500px; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello World!</div>
<button id="showWidthBtn">Show Width</button>
```

Comment: thank you for the help i forgot to add that i need `display:block`

Comment: @tq `inline-block` not `block`, the display of `div` is `block` by default

Answer (score 1):

As others point out, the parent container's width is an upper bound to its child. This snippet shows a child blue div in a red parent div. Though the max width on the blue child is set to 1500, its actual width which is captured by jquery as `$('.blue').width()` shows below 1500.

```js
$('#output').append($('.blue').width());
```

```css
.blue { /* child */
  max-width: 1500px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.red { /* parent */
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
<p id="output">The blue width is bound by its red parent. Blue's width is now: </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. `outerWidth()` does that: http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

Comment: `outerWidth()` gave me the `max-width` value

Comment: @Huangism try resizing the output window of the jsbin and then press "run with JS" to see the results. The number adapts to the actual size of the div. It's not always 600. The only time it's 600 is when the output window is too wide.

Comment: @AlexStack well of course it will because the container of the div is smaller as I explained in my first comment. The OP would not of posted this question if he had a browser width smaller than 600