# How to find the width of a string efficiently using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to find the width of a string variable if it were to be displayed on the screen. The technique I've found for doing this entails using a `span`, filling it with the string in question and then measuring the width of that `span`. Unfortunately I need to calculate the width of my string a couple hundred times during the loading of my page to determine the dimensions of various elements on my screen. The calls to the existing version of this function takes about 95% of my execution time and I'm wondering if there's a faster way to calculate the width of a string that maybe doesn't use the DOM which I'm assuming is why this function is bottlenecking my page. The code I'm using to calculate string width presently looks like this:

```
<script>
String.prototype.strWidth = function(){
    $("#ruler").html(this);
    return $("#ruler").width();
};
</script>
<span id="ruler" style="visibility:hidden;white-space:nowrap"></span>
```

Comment: Care to explain WHY you need to calculate the width of the screen? There is no guarantee that your string width is going to be the same for all users depending on the browser settings, etc, and if it has anything to do with formatting it would probably much better be done with css.

Comment: not the width of the screen. the width of the string if it were displayed on the screen. I'm trying to display divs in place of those selects, hopefully of an appropriate width, so I don't have to load hundred of selects when the page loads which takes a long time.

Comment: Indeed. And depending on the user's font size settings, or screen width and the way it affects the elements in the dom, the width of the string itself will be changing. Different fonts are used depending on the language packs available, etc, many things could cause it to be inconsistent. Hence, why knowing why would be good. If there's a good reason for it, then we can figure it out. But odds are there is a different and simpler way to accomplish your goal. So, worth checking what the goal is :)

Comment: My comment edited with why I need to get the string's width.

Comment: So why don't you just create the div with the text in it?

Comment: I want the width of the div to reflect the width of the widest option in the select. The reason for this is that I'm trying to mimic the appearance of the library I'm using to display the selects once I fully instantiate them (ParamQuery Multiselect) and that's what it does and I don't want the size of the UI element that the user sees to change when they click on it.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616393/how-to-get-actual-width-of-div-when-max-width-is-set/28616443#28616443

Comment: @SebastianLorenzo The OP is already doing that, what does your comment add to what the OP did?

Comment: @JuanMendes It can be applied to any tag, without it necessary a span tag. Maybe it was helpful

Comment: Try setting `position:absolute` so that measuring the  element doesn't cause a reflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the canvas' `measureText` method.

I know w3 isn't the best, but this link explains it: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

Just have a hidden canvas in your DOM:

```
<canvas id="secret-canvas"></canvas>

var stringBounds = function(string, style) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("secret-canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // Specify the styling
    context.font = style;
    return context.measureText(string);
}

console.log(stringBounds("hello???", "12px sans-serif").width);
```

For performance gains you could create a reference to `context` a single time in the global scope, and then use that reference in `stringBounds` instead of calculating `context` every time.

Comment: The problem is that this only works for canvas, the OP's code will tell you the length of a string with all the CSS applied to it (kerning, font-stretch)

Comment: It's not perfect because of what @JuanMendes pointed out but it executes much faster and gives me a result that at least approximates the correct result. Fortunately there's not a lot of CSS for me to consider in terms of how the text is displayed on my page.

Comment: It definitely has its problems - but this is THE way to efficiently calculate rendered string width. I am confident in saying that there may be no efficient way to get the bounds of strings which are styled in a complicated manner. Glad it worked in your case!

Comment: Do you really want an "approximate" result? If you underestimate the size of the string by one pixel and allocate space for it accordingly, it will spill over onto the next line. Or else it will create a scrollbar or something equally ugly.

Comment: That ought to be kept in mind, and probably handled with `white-space: nowrap`, ensuring that the container is sufficiently long, or any other method. As I said, I believe this is THE method for efficient string bound calculation. Until someone else comes up with an improvement on this, I'll hold the belief that there is no way to *efficiently* calculate string bounds for a string with multifarious styling.

Answer (score 0):

For an efficiency upgrade, you could simply change up how often you do a jQuery selector:

```
<script>
String.prototype.strWidth = (function() {
    // Keep variable in closed-over function (don't pollute global scope)
    var $ruler = $('<span>');
    return function() {
        $ruler.html(this);
        return $ruler.width();
    };
})();
</script>
```

Edit: Used a virtual `span`

Comment: You have to put this in a `DOM ready` handler otherwise `$('#ruler')` will be an empty `jQuery` object